# MySQL I/O wait time suddenly increasing

Tags: mysql

The I/O wait time is increasing for one of my servers. I haven't seen any long running queries in the process list. Can someone help me identify the cause?

The server is running Cent OS Linux 7.7, 4 core CPU , MySQL version 5.6.42

**iotop output**

```
Actual DISK READ:      57.85 M/s | Actual DISK WRITE:      74.90 K/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
31529 be/4 mysql      58.08 M/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 84.45 % mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib~p.geolearning.com.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306
12331 be/4 mysql       7.68 K/s   61.46 K/s  0.00 %  0.66 % mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib~p.geolearning.com.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306
 6819 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.02 % [kworker/2:16]
    1 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 22
    2 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kthreadd]
    4 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/0:0H]
    6 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/0]
    7 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/0]
    8 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [rcu_bh]
    9 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [rcu_sched]
   10 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [lru-add-drain]
```

Processlist:

+---------+----------------+------------------+---------+---------+------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------------+
| Id      | User           | Host             | db      | Command | Time | State        | Info                                                                                                 | Rows_sent | Rows_examined |
+---------+----------------+------------------+---------+---------+------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------------+
| 2128874 | lpaauser       | 10.7.40.7:64197  | prodsup | Query   | 0    | Sending data | REPLACE INTO course_auto_assignments_compute8 (domain_id,lms_user_id,filter_set_id)
                    S | 0         | 0             |
| 2129350 | mveeranki      | localhost        |         | Query   | 0    | init         | show processlist                                                                                     | 0         | 0             |
+---------+----------------+------------------+---------+---------+------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; and first page of TOP report.

Comment: Tasks: 162 total,   1 running, 161 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 19.5 us,  1.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 51.2 id, 27.3 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 32780576 total,   230476 free, 28015504 used,  4534596 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  3999740 total,  3394556 free,   605184 used.  3131056 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 3187 mysql     20   0   28.4g  26.3g   1628 S  85.0 84.2  42508:01 mysqld
   45 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   1.3  0.0 476:00.27 kswapd0
    1 root      20   0   43648   2336

Comment: 2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:02.55 kthreadd
    4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
    6 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:37.96 ksoftirqd/0
    7 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.09 migration/0
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0  18:31.24 rcu_sched
   10 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 lru-add-drain

Comment: In processlist only one replace query is running

Comment: Thanks, Now we can see you have 32GB RAM, 4GB swap space and 161 Sleeping tasks. Could you post to pastebin.com (or similar storage) A) complete TEXT results of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; so we can see HOW LONG your sleepers have been hanging around in the PID list? and B) current IOTOP results. Share the pastebin URL(s) after posting, please.